# Problem with Run button in python 3.x on VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have problems running python files in VS code, like run button is not working sometimes and also it's showing 2 options to run file. as shown in the screenshot. [Python 3.x on VS code on WIN 10 Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT8Yx.png)

Comment: I have the same issue with two options shown on pressing run button. Before the recent VS code update the run button was invoking the "Code Runner" extension and I was happy with it.